# AngularJS ng-class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I set ng-class for table cells in following manner:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="t in report.tags|orderBy:'seq'" data-ng-class='{red : state==3 || state==4 , green: state==1 || state==2}'> {{ t.cell_content}}</td>
```

where `state` is an attribute of object from array `tags` (so it is accessible as t.state)

in CSS I have these lines:

```
.red {
    background: red; 
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

However cells remain white even if other parameters of this CSS file (in another part of code) work fine.

Where am I wrong?

Note: that use of `t.state` doesn't resolve the problem.
I am sure that `state` has only values 1,2,3 or 4

Comment: Can you please recreate the issue using an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please provide minimal example of your problem in plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: if `state` is stored in each `t` as you said then of course you need to use `t.state` and not just `state`

Comment: if you provide an example on jsfiddle that describe your problem it would much more useful to help than one line of html

Comment: I made a jsfiddle based on your code, and it works. There must be something else wrong with your code. Show us more. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29839/

Comment: After adding () to conditions it started to work....who knows why....but works...Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question truly, state is property of object in array so here is example on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32219/) that works correctly  I just use **t.state** instead of **state** and everything else works fine

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="test">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat='t in arr'  data-ng-class='
  {red : t.state==3 || t.state==4 ,green: t.state==1 || t.state==2}'> {{t.state}}
  </td>    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

and angular controller will looks like this

```
function test($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [{
        state: 1
    }, {
        state: 2
    }, {
        state: 3
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, I have added brackets `()` to my conditions and it magically started to work

```
   <td data-ng-repeat="t in report.tags|orderBy:'seq'" data-ng-class='{red : (t.state==3 || t.state==4) , green: (t.state==1 || t.state==2)}'> {{ t.cell_content}}</td>
```

Answer (score -3):

Shouldn't you be using `t.state` rather than `state`. And single quote `''` around your desired class names?

```
<td data-ng-repeat="t in report.tags|orderBy:'seq'" data-ng-class='{'red' : t.state==3 || t.state==4 , 'green': t.state==1 || t.state==2}'> {{ t.cell_content}}</td>
```

Comment: single quote ' ' is optional for one word. If you have words like my-class then you should quote my-class with 'my-class'